# CSS3: box-shadow transition not working on pseudo class

Tags: html, css

I've encountered something strange with my box-shadow across all browsers.

### **What I want to do:**

Smooth the box-shadow on my inputs when they are in :focus.

### **Problem:**

the following code works just fine, and the transition is smooth:
Note how I omit the box-shadow in "default" state.

```css
#message-main #message {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em 0.75em;
  border-radius: $border-radius-input;
  background-color: $background-input;
  //box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #a7a7a7, -5px -5px 8px #f5f5f5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 39px;
  resize: vertical;
  resize: block;
}

#message-main #message:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 8px #a7a7a7, inset -5px -5px 8px #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div id="message-main">
  <label class="label is-required" for="message">Ihre Nachricht</label>
  <textarea id="message" class="inputfields required" name="message" rows="10" cols="46" placeholder="Schreiben Sie uns Ihre Nachricht." maxlength="1250" spellcheck="true" required></textarea>
</div>
```

As soon as I include the box-shadow for the default state, the transition is no longer smooth but is still working.

```css
#message-main #message {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em 0.75em;
  border-radius: $border-radius-input;
  background-color: $background-input;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #a7a7a7, -5px -5px 8px #f5f5f5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 39px;
  resize: vertical;
  resize: block;
}

#message-main #message:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 8px #a7a7a7, inset -5px -5px 8px #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div id="message-main">
  <label class="label is-required" for="message">Ihre Nachricht</label>
  <textarea id="message" class="inputfields required" name="message" rows="10" cols="46" placeholder="Schreiben Sie uns Ihre Nachricht." maxlength="1250" spellcheck="true" required></textarea>
</div>
```

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: give the same box-shadow in both states and only chage the color (from transparent to the needed color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in latter snippet you change the direction of box-shadow from default (when not specify too) `outset` to `inset`. 
 Run my snippet to better undertand the point. Also read this great article about performance of box-shadow tranisition https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/how-to-animate-box-shadow/

```css
#message-main #message {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0.75em 0.5em 0.75em;
  border-radius: $border-radius-input;
  background-color: $background-input;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #a7a7a7, inset 0px 0px 0px #f5f5f5;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 39px;
  resize: vertical;
  resize: block;
}

#message-main #message:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 8px #a7a7a7, inset -5px -5px 8px #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div id="message-main">
  <label class="label is-required" for="message">Ihre Nachricht</label>
  <textarea id="message" class="inputfields required" name="message" rows="10" cols="46" placeholder="Schreiben Sie uns Ihre Nachricht." maxlength="1250" spellcheck="true" required></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the above help I was able to solve my issue while retaining the shadow direction:

```
      box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 8px transparent,
      inset -5px -5px 8px transparent, 5px 5px 8px #a7a7a7,
      -5px -5px 8px #f5f5f5;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Glad you did it 